# Why doesn't "first waters" in hand washing make the hand tamei?

Tags: netilat-yadayim-washing, maseches-yadayim

In Mishnah [Yadayim 2:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Yadayim.2.3?lang=bi), we learn that the "first waters" (the first of two splashes of water) poured on the hands while doing ritual hand-washing is *tamei* (if less than a certain amount), while the hands are *tahor*. We also see that if after pouring the first waters, you touch your hands to each other, the hands become *tamei*.

> הַיָּדַיִם מִטַּמְּאוֹת וּמִטַּהֲרוֹת עַד הַפֶּרֶק. כֵּיצַד. נָטַל אֶת הָרִאשׁוֹנִים עַד הַפֶּרֶק, וְאֶת הַשְּׁנִיִּים חוּץ לַפֶּרֶק, וְחָזְרוּ לַיָּד, טְהוֹרָה. נָטַל אֶת הָרִאשׁוֹנִים וְאֶת הַשְּׁנִיִּים חוּץ לַפֶּרֶק וְחָזְרוּ לַיָּד, טְמֵאָה. נָטַל אֶת הָרִאשׁוֹנִים לְיָדוֹ אַחַת וְנִמְלַךְ וְנָטַל אֶת הַשְּׁנִיִּים לִשְׁתֵּי יָדָיו, טְמֵאוֹת. נָטַל אֶת הָרִאשׁוֹנִים לִשְׁתֵּי יָדָיו וְנִמְלַךְ וְנָטַל אֶת הַשְּׁנִיִּים לְיָדוֹ אַחַת, יָדוֹ טְהוֹרָה. נָטַל לְיָדוֹ אַחַת וְשִׁפְשְׁפָהּ בַּחֲבֶרְתָּהּ, טְמֵאָה. בְּרֹאשׁוֹ אוֹ בַכֹּתֶל, טְהוֹרָה. נוֹטְלִין אַרְבָּעָה וַחֲמִשָּׁה זֶה בְצַד זֶה אוֹ זֶה עַל גַּבֵּי זֶה, וּבִלְבַד שֶׁיְּרַפּוּ שֶׁיָּבֹאוּ בָהֶם הַמָּיִם:
>
> Hands become unclean and are made clean as far as the joint. How so? If he poured the first water over the hands as far as the joint and poured the second water over the hands beyond the joint and the latter flowed back to the hands, the hands are clean. If he poured the first and the second water over the hands beyond the joint and they flowed back to the hands, the hands remain unclean. If he poured the first water over one of his hands and then changed his mind and poured the second water over both his hands, they are unclean. If he poured the first water over both his hands and then changed his mind and poured the second water over one of his hands, his one hand becomes clean. If he poured water over one of his hands and rubbed it on the other hand it remains unclean. If he rubbed it on his head or on the wall it is clean. Water may be poured over the hands of four or five persons, each hand being by the side of the other, or being one above the other, provided that the hands are held loosely so that the water flows between them.

If the *tamei* water on one hand can make the other hand *tamei* by touch, why does it not make *tamei* the hand it was poured on? I guess that this could just be part of the Rabbinic enactment (since this *tumah* is entirely Rabbinic), but if so, why not just require a minimum quantity in the first instance, such that no water becomes *tamei*?

Comment: To the extent you view the reviit in a kli like a pseudo-mikvah, they might not have wanted to deviate too much from regular water rules where little amounts accept tumah.

Comment: There is an answer in the Arukh haShulchan OC 162 https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.162 . I am just too tired to extract it.

Comment: why not just require a minimum quantity in the first instance, such that no water becomes tamei? **you do not always have so much water**

Comment: Might be related: "As part of the decree of Tumas Yadayim and Netillas Yadayim, the rule is so long as the מים ראשונים remain on the hand, it does not have the power to make either the hand or the subsequent מים שניים טמא." (https://www.sefaria.org.il/sheets/47899.51?lang=bi)

Comment: @MichaBerger I don't see an answer to this question in there.

Comment: @Harel13 Definitely seems related, but it's just an assertion without any supporting evidence.

Comment: @Daniel - the Arukh haShulchan discusses how to avoid having the first pouring be machshir the hands to be metam'im with the second pouring.